# Load scripts js in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have been using Angular 4 with AdminLTE which needs to run some scripts to load properly.
I have included scripts in my index.html and the first page works perfectly... The problem is when I route to another page which requires to load the same scripts (from login page to home page). The page loads fine without errors but because of scripts are not loaded, some button,, databale not work. If I refresh browser the page is displayed fine again. I used the angular 4 router with 
index.html

```
    <body class="hold-transition skin-green sidebar-mini">

  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
  <!--reCaptcha -->
  <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
  <!-- jQuery 3 -->
  <script src="assets/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
  <script src="assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- SlimScroll -->
  <script src="assets/bower_components/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
  <!-- FastClick -->
  <script src="assets/bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
  <!-- AdminLTE App -->
  <script src="assets/dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
  <!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
  <script src="assets/dist/js/demo.js"></script>
  <!-- CK Editor -->
  <script src="assets/bower_components/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function () {
        // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
        // instance, using default configuration.
        CKEDITOR.replace('editor1')
        //bootstrap WYSIHTML5 - text editor
        $('.textarea').wysihtml5()
    })
  </script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.sidebar-menu').tree()
    })
  </script>

</body>
```

route

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'accueil', component: AccueilComponent },
  { path: 'dossier', component: DossierComponent },
```

];

```
RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
```

Comment: Angular is a single page application, so it only loads your index.html once then navigates between routes on the client side. If you need your scripts to load on every route change, you'll need to manually load them on route change.

Comment: You should not load scripts like that. It defeats the purpose of using modules. Use your loader to handle this. Do you use Webpack or SystemJS or something else?

Comment: thank you for your quick reply ,, PLEASE @LLai show me an example how i could to load scripts on route change ?

Comment: @AluanHaddad i have used  Angular 4 with AdminLTE (https://adminlte.io/)

Comment: @JohnDoe I understand that, but you should modify the index file so it doesn't load all these scripts and thus create all these global variables like `$`. JQuery is a proper AMD library and it only creates that global as a fallback.